# Uploading a .ttl file to Fuseki using Java client - where are my triples in Fuseki?

Tags: jena, fuseki

I have a Fuseki server running in my local Windows 11 Docker Desktop.

To load ttl files from java I am following https://jena.apache.org/documentation/rdfconnection/

which gives me code

```
        String localFile = "mdworking.ttl";
        ZzzHelperFile.saveStringToFile(myTttString, localFile);
        String serviceURL = "http://localhost:3030/mdtest/";
        RDFConnectionRemoteBuilder builder = RDFConnectionFuseki.create()
                .destination(serviceURL);
        RDFConnectionFuseki conn = (RDFConnectionFuseki) builder.build();
        {
            conn.load(localFile) ;
            conn.querySelect("SELECT DISTINCT ?s { ?s ?p ?o }", (qs) -> {
                Resource subject = qs.getResource("s") ;
                System.out.println("Subject: " + subject) ;
            }) ;
        }
```

The output is what I would expect, the list of my Subject.

The Fuseki service output in Docker does not seem unreasonable, (although I dont know what ?default is):

```
2023-07-03 17:02:27 16:02:27 INFO  Fuseki          :: [96] POST http://localhost:3030/mdtest/?default
2023-07-03 17:02:27 16:02:27 INFO  Fuseki          :: [96] Body: Content-Length=117, Content-Type=text/turtle, Charset=UTF-8 => Turtle : Count=4 Triples=4 Quads=0
2023-07-03 17:02:27 16:02:27 INFO  Fuseki          :: [96] 200 OK (80 ms)
2023-07-03 17:02:28 16:02:28 INFO  Fuseki          :: [97] GET http://localhost:3030/mdtest/?query=SELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fs+%7B+%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo+%7D
2023-07-03 17:02:28 16:02:28 INFO  Fuseki          :: [97] Query = SELECT DISTINCT ?s { ?s ?p ?o }
2023-07-03 17:02:28 16:02:28 INFO  Fuseki          :: [97] 200 OK (28 ms)
```

But then I go to the Fuseki front end my triples are not there in the mdtest dataset.

What I can find at http://localhost:3030/mdtest/?default in the browser are my test triples

```
@prefix : <http://www.oxfordsemantic.tech/Turtle/> .
:crush  a        :turtle ;
        :eats    :coral ;
        :enjoys  :swimming ;
        :is      :cool .
```

If I change the name of mdtest to something that is not a Fuseki dataset then my code throws a not found exception.

Why are my triples not in the Fuseki mdtest dataset that I can see from the Fuseki UI?

Docker image:

`ENV FUSEKI_VERSION=4.2.0`

POM

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
            <artifactId>jena-arq</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jena/jena-rdfconnection -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
            <artifactId>jena-rdfconnection</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Which version of Fuseki are you running? I get one result as expected using your example after replacing ZzzHelperFilewith IO.writeStringAsUTF8(localFile, data) and you example data. What exactly is myTttString?

Comment: Also - try a HTTP connection:
`try( RDFConnection conn = RDFConnectionRemote.create().destination(serviceURL).build() ) {...}`

Comment: @AndyS Version is 4.2.0. I will paste pom and docker in question. But now I know more - if I take out the setting tdb2:unionDefaultGraph true from the dataset.ttl file 

rdf:type      tdb2:DatasetTDB2 ;
tdb2:location "mdtest" ;
tdb2:unionDefaultGraph true .

the triples are showing in the Fuseki front end, as expect. I was thinking unionDefaultGraph true meant all named graphs were included when I did select * WHERE {?s ?p ?o}. Do I have that wrong?

Comment: New information! See answer.

Comment: Writing a string to a file and using load can also be done by parsing to a model and using `load(URI, model)`. No external file necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the use of `tdb2:unionDefaultGraph`.

The union is a view of triples in the named graphs - the default graph is not a named graph.

An update goes to the real storage, not the union view.
It goes to the real storage default graph.

If you send the `RDFConnection.load(graph name, filename)` operation to a named graph, the triples will appear to a query.

Comment: Ok, so  ```tdb2:unionDefaultGraph``` does not include the default graph! Good to know. I will forgive myself for not picking that up. Many thanks.