# Fuseki shows "No data available in table" even so there is data

Tags: rdf, jena, fuseki, tdb

When I Query my dataset in the Fuseki UI with this predefined query:

```
SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object
WHERE {
  ?subject ?predicate ?object
}
LIMIT 25
```

it responses with no data available.

However, if I'm open the edit tab and click on the default graph it shows all my data.

I recon that it is a configure issue, but cant find any hint in the documentation.

The endpoint is set to anon in shiro

```
/**/query = anon
```

And the Endpoints are configured in the most basic way:

```
fuseki:endpoint [ 
        fuseki:operation fuseki:query ;
        fuseki:name "sparql" ;
        ## Set default-union-graph for this endpoint.
        ja:context [ ja:cxtName "tdb:unionDefaultGraph" ; ja:cxtValue true ] ;
    ] ;
    fuseki:endpoint [
        fuseki:operation fuseki:query ;
        fuseki:name "query" 
    ] ;
```

When I'm query the data via http, the server response with a ttl file containing all my data:

```
http://localhost:8081/dataset/data?default
```

The Fuseki Server and Webapp runs inside a docker container using the following compose configuration:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: tomcat:9.0
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./logs/fuseki:/etc/fuseki/logs
      - ./logs/tomcat:/usr/local/tomcat/logs
      - ./triplestore/ROOT.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
      - ./shiro.ini:/etc/fuseki/shiro.ini
      - ./config.ttl:/etc/fuseki/config.ttl
```

Any suggestion for why the querys dont work are appreciated.

I tried querieng using the WebUI and via curl, both with the same result. Only downloading via http works.

**EDIT: The way I put my data in the store**

I use a python script to load my data into the store.

```
def write_to_fuseki():
    print('write to fuseki')
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/turtle;charset=utf-8'}
    r = requests.put('http://localhost:8081/dataset/data?default',headers=headers, data=open('ontology/test.ttl', 'rb'), auth=('user', 'pw'))
```

Comment: Okay, there seems to be something wrong with the way I put my data into the store. When I create a new dataset in the manage-menu and upload the ttl I just downloaded via http as shown above, it works fine. Meaning, the Data shows up in a query. 
Also, in the edit tab, my regular dataset shows a 0 in the count column, the test dataset shows a bigger number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in this question:

[Uploading a .ttl file to Fuseki using Java client - where are my triples in Fuseki?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76606561/uploading-a-ttl-file-to-fuseki-using-java-client-where-are-my-triples-in-fuse?rq=2)

It appears the union default graph setting was not doing what I expected. I changed the config, and removed all unionDefaultGraph settings and know my data appears in the search.

```
:service rdf:type fuseki:Service ;
fuseki:name "dataset" ;
fuseki:endpoint [ 
    fuseki:operation fuseki:query ;
    fuseki:name "sparql" ;
] ;
fuseki:endpoint [
    fuseki:operation fuseki:query ;
    fuseki:name "query" 
] ;
fuseki:endpoint [
    fuseki:operation fuseki:update ;
    fuseki:name "update"
] ;
fuseki:endpoint [
    fuseki:operation fuseki:gsp-r ;
    fuseki:name "get"
] ;
fuseki:endpoint [ 
    fuseki:operation fuseki:gsp-rw ; 
    fuseki:name "data"
] ; 
fuseki:endpoint [ 
    fuseki:operation fuseki:patch ;
    fuseki:name "patch"
] ; 
fuseki:dataset :dataset_tdb2 ;
.
```

:dataset_tdb2 rdf:type  tdb2:DatasetTDB2 ;
tdb2:location "databases/db"
.